# How to apply a default value into specflow step definition table even if the user does not provide the column name

Tags: c#, restsharp, specflow, gherkin, rest-client

How to apply a default value into the specflow step definition table even if the user does not provide the column name?

Example:
This is my feature file

```
@regression @add-a-new-cat
Feature: Add a new cat
  As a User
  I should be able to add a cat

  # Vocabulary:
  # User: An authorized application user

  @positive @smoke-test
  Scenario: Add a new cat
    Given the User is authorized to add a new cat
    When the User adds new cat
    | CatName | Age | Breed  |
    | Kitty   | 5   | Indian |
    | Lucy   | 5   | Persian |
    Then the cat is added successfully
```

Ideal case step definition:

```
[When(@"the User adds new cat")]
public async void WhenTheUserAddsNewCatEndpointAsync(Table table)
{
    var addCats = table.CreateSet<CatDetails>();
    var request = new RestRequest("cats");
    request.AddBody(addCats);
    restResponse = await restSharpRetryDriver.restClient.ExecutePostAsync(request);
}
```

Now my requirement is - how can I pass a default value to a data table column if the user does not pass all the columns in the datatable.

Example:

```
@regression @add-a-new-cat
Feature: Add a new cat
  As a User
  I should be able to add a cat

  # Vocabulary:
  # User: An authorized application user

  @positive @smoke-test
  Scenario: Add a new cat
    Given the User is authorized to add a new cat
    When the User adds new cat
    | CatName | Age |
    | Kitty   | 5   |
    | Lucy    | 5   |
    Then the cat is added successfully
```

Now the step definition should assign a default value for the "Breed" Column.
A solution that I'm aware of is:

```
[When(@"the User adds new cat")]
public async void WhenTheUserAddsNewCatEndpointAsync(Table table)
{
    var addCats = table.CreateSet<CatDetails>();
    foreach (var row in addCats)
    {
        if (row.Breed == null)
        {
           row.Breed = "persian"; // Assigning a default value, if the column name is not passed from the feature file
        }
    }
    var request = new RestRequest("cats");
    request.AddBody(addCats);
    restResponse = await restSharpRetryDriver.restClient.ExecutePostAsync(request);
}
```

OR

```
public class AddCatSteps
{
    public class CatDetails
    {
        [TableAliases("Name", "CatName")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        //public string Breed { get; set; }
        string _breed;
        public string Breed
        {
            get
            {
                if (_breed == null)
                {
                    return "newBreed";
                }
                else
                {
                    return _breed;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                _breed = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [When(@"the User adds new cat")]
    public async void WhenTheUserAddsNewCatEndpointAsync(Table table)
    {
        var addCats = table.CreateSet<CatDetails>();
        var request = new RestRequest("cats");
        request.AddBody(addCats);
        restResponse = await restSharpRetryDriver.restClient.ExecutePostAsync(request);
    }
}
```

But this does not seem like the best solution, especially if many columns are involved.
Can anyone suggest a better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If using a recent enough version of C#, simply set the default value after the definition of the property:

```
public class CatDetails
{
    public string Breed { get; set; } = "newBreed";
```

Or, simply set this in the default constructor for CatDetails:

```
public class CatDetails
{
    public string Breed { get; set; }

    public CatDetails()
    {
        Breed = "newBreed";
    }
```

The `table.CreateSet<T>()` and `table.CreateInstance<T>()` methods call the default constructor of `T`.